# Android How do I emulate the behavior of @android:id/empty in a GridView?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a gridview that is populated by a cursor that fetches data from SQLITE database. At times, there is no data to be shown. This shows a blank activity.

I had earlier used listview where I could use @android:id/empty to set an emptyView like "no data found".

Is there any similar feature for GridView that I can make use of?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ListActivity and `ListFragment` simply search for a view with that ID and call

```
listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

You can mimic this behavior in your `GridView`..

```
TextView emptyView = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
gridView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

Note that you don't need to set your empty view's ID to `@android:id/empty`. It can be anything you want as long as you are setting it in code.

[Link to GridView setEmptyView docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29)